# Downgrade Mysql 5.5.9 to 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, downgrade

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 Mysql 5.5.9 is incompatible with some of my scripts. I need to re-install Mysql 5.1. I tried research online but no luck

When I do

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.1 mysql-client-5.1

Package mysql-server-5.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mysql-server-core-5.5:i386 mysql-server-5.5:i386 mysql-server-core-5.5
  mysql-server-5.5

E: Package 'mysql-server-5.1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mysql-client-5.1' has no installation candidate

Tried to find multiverse source but no luck,
Anyone?

Comment: I assume your title should be *Downgrade Mysql 5.5.9 to 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04* too.

Comment: What incompatible changes (there were some) do break your scripts? Maybe you could configure MySQL so that your scripts will work? But generally I think this question would be better asked af [Ask Ubunutu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**Uninstall existing mysql**

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
```

**Download the MySQL APT repository config tool (as root)**

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1debian8_all.deb
```

**Install the MySQL APT repository config tool**

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1debian8_all.deb
```

**Update APT**

```
apt-get update
```

**Install the server**

```
apt-get install mysql-community-server
```

Thereby you can select the server you need and install